# Contentful/Laravel Delivery API setInclude does not work as expected

Tags: laravel, contentful

While using the contentful laravel sdk the set include is not fetching any of the assets that belong to the entries I fetch. The code below (mine):

```
    public function index()
{
    $query = $this->query
        ->setContentType('gallery')
        ->setInclude(10);

    $entry = $this->client->getEntries($query);

    if (!$entry) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $data = ['galleries' => $entry];

    return view('welcome', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

The contenful example:

```
    // contentful.php 3.0

$client = new Contentful\Delivery\Client(
  '<content_delivery_api_key>',
  '<space_id>',
  '<environment_id>' // Defaults to "master" if ommitted
);

$query = (new Contentful\Delivery\Query())
    ->setInclude(2);

$entries = $client->getEntries($query);
```

my results:

[[image]]

I expect for the previewImage and Images array to include the 'fields' that contain the location of the file. I only get 'sys'. I can't see why the include is not fetching this data. If i set setInclude to 20, over the limit i get an error. Below

[image]

What should i do differently? I achieved the desired results in a javascript frontend project, but with laravel i get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The `include` is actually working fine. Internally, linked entries/assets are represented using a `Link` object, which is resolved to an actual entry/asset as soon as you access the field (in your case, that's done with `$entry->getPreviewImage()`, which will return the Asset object that was loaded in your previous query).

This means that if you dump the entry you won't see the actual object you're expecting in the `previewImage` field, but everything will work fine if in regular use.